# Express: Error passing res.json as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scope

I have something like this:

```
...
var someService = function(next) {
    var result = {"some": "json"};
    next(result);
};

app.get('/someRoute', function (req, res) {
    someService(function (result) {
        res.json(result);
    });
});
...
```

I want to change the get to this:

```
app.get('/someRoute', function (req, res) {
    someService(res.json);
});
```

but it gives me:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined at res.json
>   (.../node_modules/express/lib/response.js:185:22) at someService

I guess the problem is something about the scope. What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the scope of methods in Javascript are bound syntactically.

Inside the res.json method, it references `this`. When called like `res.json(/* some arg */)`, `this` evaluates to `res`. When you pass in `res.json` as a callback, like `someService(res.json);`, `this` is no longer bound to `res`.

You could change it to `someService(res.json.bind(res));` to get your desired result, by explicitly binding `this` to `res`.

MDN articles:

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)

[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)